# CheckBox will uncheck and check when scrolling down the listview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-checkbox

In my application I use this to count the checked checkbox in real time meaning when tick the box the count above will increase or decrease. but when scrolling down the listview the checked box will be uncheck. any suggestion or problem in my codes?

**MainActivity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lstdept;
    CheckBox list_view_item_checkbox;
    SimpleAdapter ADAhere;
    Connection con;
    String un, pass, db, ip, z,country;
    int test = 0;
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        country = getIntent().getStringExtra("country");
        SelectRes(country);
          lstdept.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        lstdept.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (view != null) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_item_checkbox);
                    checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
                    if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        test = test - 1 ;
                    } else {
                        test = test + 1 ;
                    }
                }
               getSupportActionBar().setTitle(country + "              Total Count: " + lstdept.getCount()+"       " + test);
            }

        });

    }
```

**Use to populate listview**

```
void SelectRes(String dept) {
        ip = "172.18.130.19";
        db = "DTRSPH";
        un = "moreface";
        pass = "moreface1234";
        try {
            con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);        // Connect to database
            if (con == null) {
                toast.makeText(this,"Check Your Internet Access!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                String query = "SELECT FULLNAME FROM tblEPR where DEPT ='"+ dept +"'";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
                data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString("FULLNAME"));
                    data.add(datanum);
                }

                String[] fromwhere = {"A"};
                int[] viewswhere = {R.id.lblDept};
                ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(Main2Activity.this, data,
                        R.layout.list_emp, fromwhere, viewswhere);
                lstdept = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstemployee);
                lstdept.setAdapter(ADAhere);
                con.close();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(dept + "              Total Count: " + lstdept.getCount());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Connection to database**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";databaseName=" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @FaizMir i already post all my codes above. I'm using simple adapter.

Comment: I have written tutorial for the same long ago please check this - http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html

Comment: @WasimK.Memon hi sir, your tutorial help me a lot. my i have problem again.. how can i get the count of all check item when ticking the checkbox.. I'll input this using this code  getSupportActionBar().setTitle but i get error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is not using `holder`
make a `bean` and `adapter` like @Athira says
then inside adapter in getView  try this

```
@Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   ViewHolder holder = null;

 if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_list_item,viewGroup,false);
            holder.phone1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone1);
            holder.name1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
            holder.tick= (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.tick);
 view.setTag(holder);
}else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
           holder.phone1.setText(contactModels.get(i).getPhone());
           holder.name1.setText(contactModels.get(i).getName());
            if(contactModels.get(i).isSel())
            {
                holder.tick.setSelected(true);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.tick.setSelected(true);
            }
     holder.tick.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    contactModels.get(i).setSel(isChecked);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
 public class ViewHolder {
        TextView phone1,name1;
CheckBox tick;

    }
    }
```

Comment: glad i could help:)

Answer (score 2):

In your adapter object add a boolean parameter for check and un-check. By default set false for each item in the list, when checked set as true in adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged().

> Use a model class

```
     public class ContactModel {
        String phone,name;
        boolean sel;


        public ContactModel(String phone, String name, boolean sel) {
            this.phone = phone;
            this.name = name;
            this.sel = sel;

        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isSel() {
            return sel;
        }

        public void setSel(boolean sel) {
            this.sel = sel;
        }
```

My custom adapter

```
public class ContactADAPTER extends BaseAdapter {
    String phone,name;
    boolean sel;
 Activity act;
    List<ContactModel> contactModels;

    public ContactADAPTER(Activity act, List<ContactModel> contactModels) {
        this.act = act;
        this.contactModels = contactModels;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return contactModels.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_list_item,viewGroup,false);
        TextView phone1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone1);
        TextView name1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        CheckBox tick= (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.tick);
        phone1.setText(contactModels.get(i).getPhone());
        name1.setText(contactModels.get(i).getName());
        if(contactModels.get(i).isSel())
        {
            tick.setSelected(true);
        }
        else
        {
            tick.setSelected(true);
        }
 tick.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                contactModels.get(i).setSel(isChecked);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
//for getting ticked count

int count=0;
for(ContactModel c:contactModels)
{
if(c.isSel())
{
count++;
}
}
// show count
act.getActionBar().setTitle(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }
```

In Activity

```
 List<ContactModel> cmodelList= new ArrayList<>();
      cmodelList.add(new ContactModel(phonenumber, name, false));
      cmodelList.add(new ContactModel(phonenumber2, name2, false));
      cmodelList.add(new ContactModel(phonenumber3, name3, false));

           ContactADAPTER contactAdapter=new ContactADAPTER(Phone_Contact_List.this,cmodelList);
            listView.setAdapter(contactList);
```

Comment: If you post your adapter code i can explain using that code.

Comment: Hi Athira, It shown above "use to populate listview"

Comment: If you are concerned with checkbox, use custom adapter rather than SimpleAdapter

Comment: do you have sample code or link of tutorial for that? so i can study that custom adapter

Comment: I have added my sample code, Check and ask if u have any doubts

Comment: Thanks for your support. I get your code and my listview and checkbox are now working fine. but i had a problem how to auto increase the count of checked checkbox while ticking. the number will show in actionbar.

Comment: im using this code in adapter   getSupportActionBar().setTitle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code. it suddenly crash the app when ticking the box.but when i remove this act.getActionBar().setTitle(String.valueOf(count)); it is not crashing but this code need it to know the count.

Comment: Does your activity supports actionbar?

Comment: yes..when i using actionbar main activity. it works but in listadapter class doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, i had a mistake, Now i changed my code. Try now

Comment: In previous code added activity object to model class, but it should be added to adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the list of selected checkbox and then `set` or `unset` the checkbox based on that list.

So let's say you have `selectedcheckBox` list which have the list of the selected checkbox.

```
ArrayList<> selectedcheckBox = new ArrayList<>();
```

So what you can do is:

```
lstdept.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (view != null) {
                    selectedcheckBox.add(//Add item to the list)
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_item_checkbox);
                    checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
                    if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        test = test - 1 ;
                    } else {
                        test = test + 1 ;
                    }
                }
               getSupportActionBar().setTitle(country + "              Total Count: " + lstdept.getCount()+"       " + test);
            }

        });
```

And when you are populating the listView in your adapter, make a check with `selectedcheckBox` list.
If the value is set in the list then `set` the checkbox else `unset`.

The reason why is this happening because listView recycles itself as it moves out of the view and becomes visible again. So all the values are set again as it becomes visible again. So one should maintain proper checks to inflate the view.

Comment: hi sir, still same problem when i scroll down the checked box will unchecked and some unchecked box will became checked :(

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter will have a “getView()” method that you will do all the work for populating the cells data, use getItem(position) to get the item and then update all your views in the cell during that getView() method